# remove key from associative array with single key

Tags: php

I have the following array,

```
$myarray[0]['first_name']
$myarray[0]['last_name']
```

I want to turn it into:

```
$myarray['first_name']
$myarray['last_name']
```

with a simple oneliner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this?

```
$myarray = $myarray[0];
```

Comment: Someone please comment on this to clarify if I'm correct in the following statement:  *If you save this by reference you will avoid the extra copy.*

Comment: How can you get any nicer than that?

Comment: If you don't like the syntax, don't use the language, Bren G. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Or this?

```
$myarray = current($myarray);
```

[user187291's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629684/remove-key-from-associative-array-with-single-key/1629691#1629691) still looks clearer though.